# Android media player not producing sound even playing

Tags: android, bluetooth, media-player

I have created a media player application using Android MediaPlayer API. The app is working fine unless a phone call is received. I am handling phone call events in my app and doing pause and play of media player.

The problem is that After pause and play, when phone call arrives, the song is playing but with no sound from speakers.

One more thing is This is happening when I am using bluetooth headset only.

If anybody faced this problem, please reply suggestions to my question.

Comment: I remember some phone had this problem with bluetooth. Is it HTC ?

Comment: no not HTC. I tested with Samsung and Moto Razr mobiles.

Comment: try on a different phone. If the problem persists, post your code to handle phone calls. There are various operations to suppport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by stopping bluetooth's SCO before playing a music track if it is ON.